# how to create a vertical histogram using in-built python modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

Basically I need to create a vertical histogram that cascades downwards.
My code so far:

```
a = 1
b = 8
c = 6
d = 7

x = [a, b, c, d]
z = max(x)
print(z)
i = 0
while i < z:
    i += 1
    a -= 1
    b -= 1
    c -= 1
    d -= 1
    if a >= 0:
        print("*".ljust(5), end="")
    if b >= 0:
        print("*".ljust(5), end="")
    if c >= 0:
        print("*".ljust(5), end="")
    if d >= 0:
        print("*".ljust(5))
```

output obtained:

```
*    *    *    *    
*    *    *    
*    *    *    
*    *    *    
*    *    *    
*    *    *    
*    *    
*
```

Required output:

```
*   *   *   *
    *   *   *
    *   *   *
    *   *   *
    *   *   *   
    *   *   *
    *       *
    *
```

ps: I'm new to all this so please excuse my ignorance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost working as is, but the `*`s are shifting over between columns.

If I change the *s to be the variable they are for, your current output looks like this:

```
a   b   c   d
b   c   d
b   c   d
b   c   d
b   c   d
b   c   d
b   d
b
```

You just need to print some whitespace when your if conditions come up False. So each one becomes

```
if a >= 0:
    print("*".ljust(5), end="")
else:
    print(" ".ljust(5), end="")
```